# Android search dialog shows unwanted additional suggestion list

Tags: android, android-widget

The Android search dialog below is displaying suggestions I supply using my own content provider (aardvark, another, apple). Below that list is a second list (about, all, ...) which I do not want. What is the technical term for that second list, and why is it shown? How can I suppress it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second list is an auto-completion feature which has nothing to do with your search dialog. It is a keyboard feature which suggests common words from a dictionary. It can be enabled or disabled in the keyboard preferences but the choice is up to the user.

Generally it is disabled by default but on the emulator the default settings are sometimes different (because it emulates a development device, not a production device). It can also change between languages.

If you are sure that these suggested words are useless then you can disable this feature by adding [`android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`](http://android.ankara-gtug.org/reference/android/R.attr.html#inputType) to your `<searchable>` tag.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So if I understand it correctly, tapping a word from the auto-completion list copies it to the entry field, while tapping a word from the suggestion list closes the dialog? And there's no way I can disable auto-suggestion for an individual search? In my case, the list of possible words is fixed, and they all appear in the suggestion list I provide.

Comment: *tapping a word from the auto-completion list copies it to the entry field, while tapping a word from the suggestion list closes the dialog?* Yes, this is right.